# Elasticsearch get aggregation bucket size (number of elements in the bucket) without retrieving all data

Tags: elasticsearch, size, metadata, aggregate, bucket

I am trying to get information about an aggregation in Elasticsearch.

I have an index in which I store mail metadata (sender ip, subject etc.) What I'm trying to do is I want to get number of IPs which send over 1000 mails. (So for example let's say we have 3 IP addresses, 2000 mails are sent from **first IP**, 1500 from **second** and 200 from the **third IP**. Then I want to see **2** as the aggregation result.) I wrote the following query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "ipAddresses": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "senderIpAddress",
            "min_doc_count": 1000,
            "size" : 0
         }
      }

   }
}
```

I can get the bucket and calculate its size in my back-end implementation, however I need to get all the data in the bucket in order to do this. It is slow and I want to get the bucket size without getting all the data.

TL;DR, how can I get the total size of aggregation bucket without retrieving the whole data?

Comment: I have the exact problem now. Do you have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) aggregation:

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
    "ipAddressesCount": {
       "cardinality": {
          "field": "senderIpAddress"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that it is an approximation -- the precision can be configured using `precision_threshold` as documented in the link above.

Comment: I know what a cardinality aggregation is. If you read carefully what I mentioned, I want to see number of IP addresses more than 1000 mails are sent from. If I just make a simple cardinality, then at the end of the day we will count the IP addresses less than 1000 mails are sent from.